# Remove words from a string of variable length

Tags: javascript, regex, string, twitter

I've connected to the Twitter API and managed to get tweets I want, but in order to manipulate the text the way I want, I need to remove all @mentions and all links.

I assume this would take a regex function to search for key characters (`@` and `http`?), see when the next space is in the string and stop there, then splice them out, but what would be the right pattern for each? How do you splice a single word out of a string?

Tweet retrieved:
`'@user_name lol look at this https://url.goes/here'`

Ideal Output: `'lol look at this '`
(yes, the space after 'this' is okay to keep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"@user_name lol look at this https://url.goes/here".replace(/(@[^ ]+|http[s]?:\/\/[^ ]+)/g, "");
```

It is not a perfect solution, but you can start with it.

Comment: This has the logic I'm looking for to replace strings and a useful starting regex. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best option is to find patterns, for example to remove the usernames you could loop through each character beginning at the '@' symbol and continuing until it reaches for a space. The same thing could be don't for URL's where you search for http in one single string then delete it until a space is reached.